# Special characters in the folder name

Tags: python

I am trying to make a list of all files in a folder. The folder name contains special characters.The files contains in this path: C:\yardi_backup_v2.%5C

```
import glob
filelist = glob.glob('C:\yardi_backup_v2\.%5C\*')
print(filelist)
```

It always give me an empty list.

My question is how to write this path properly.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Comment: have you tried using raw strings(r'')?

Comment: You are right, thanks for your help!